# Could not load file or assembly Crystaldecisions.shared or one of its dependencies

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have created an application on VB.NET 2010 with SQL Server 2008 database on my 64 bit operating system. The app is working perfectly on my system. I created a setup file and installed on another computer which is 32bit. It's working fine there too. However, when I try to load Crystal Reports I get this error. What steps I have taken so far to resolve this are as follows:

Installed CR runtime 32 bit on computer where I deployed the app.
In the `app.config` file I added this entry
`startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0"sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>`

3. Enable unmanaged code debugging in project properties.

Nothing worked. Please if any one can help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u9Ka.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use images for error messages - use text. Also your entire system is using out of date/out of support components... trying to make that work could be very difficult. Upgrade to the current versions.

Comment: Sometimes a dependency of your dependency is missing. Did SAP Support ask if you had already installed the vcredist_x86.exe package for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Crystal redistribution is not being installed. For this version it should be CRRedist2008_x86.msi instead of credist_x86.exe. The same error would trigger if I try to run crystal report without the component installed.

Comment: @Yat Fei Leong i have installed CRRedist2008_x86.msi too on target machine. But still give same error.

Comment: @Always learning i think you are right because when i try put primary output in the setup it gives a warning The following files may have dependencies that cannot be determined automatically.
Please confirm that all dependencies have been added to the project.
C:\windows\syswow64\macromed\flash\flash32_18_0_0_232.ocx  but i dont know what is dependent file of flash.ocx

Comment: under you project setting reference for CrystalDecision.CrystalReport.Engine, have you tried set the 'Specific Version' to FALSE?